# django popen "invalid syntax"

Tags: django, popen

I am new to Django. I would like to run some command from some view. Something like:

```
 python /path/to/the/script/run.py -id 11 --user root --run_digital_id 29 --workflow map --lib_group library.yaml --log log.conf
```

I use this method to call:

```
def run_in_background(cmd):
    logging.info('running ' + cmd)
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    output, errors = p.communicate()
    print output
    print errors
    logging.debug(output)
    logging.debug(errors)
```

The command is passed to the method run_in_background(). When I copy the command and run on the terminal, it works well. But when I run it from some view of Django, it reports:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/the/script/run.py", line 11, in ?
    import conf, util
  File "/path/to/the/script/conf.py", line 11
    class Settings():
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Er, the run_in_background method is also working when I call it from some 'plain' python code.

The error position is the first line of my program. I suspect there is something wrong with the paths... But after searching for long time, I did not get the reason. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code that is producing the error? Did you forget to indent?

Comment: @burhan: No. I can run the command from the terminal...

Comment: In some python version defining class with empty parenthesis like `class Settings():` is not valid, you may want to change it to `class Settings(object):`.

Comment: paste the lines surrounding `class Settings():` in `conf.py`

Comment: @Rohan: Thanks, it works now! Could you answer it so that I can accept your answer...

Comment: Thanks, @BurhanKhalid. As Rohan said, it is due to different python versions.

Comment: Oh, I am using python 2.6.5... So I also find some line such as "with open(filename, 'r') as f" not working. But surprisingly it works when I run it from the terminal.

Comment: This is because your terminal is using a different version of Python than your file. You can use `from __future__ import with_statement`, but it should be _the very first import line_ in your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is the solution!

In some python version defining class with empty parenthesis like `class Settings():` is not valid, you may want to change it to `class Settings(object):`